# Round-up or Round-down the SpecialOfferPrice column in this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I Round-up or  Round-down the SpecialOfferPrice column in this query?

```
SELECT  TB_Product. ProductID, 
TB_Product.RetailPrice * 0.95 AS SpecialOfferPrice
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `CEILING(numeric)` to round up.

[According to MSDN:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> This function returns the smallest integer greater than, or equal to,
>   the specified numeric expression.

```
SELECT 
CEILING(TB_Product.RetailPrice * 0.95) AS SpecialOfferPrice
```

To round down use ROUND.
[As MSDN says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Returns a numeric value, rounded to the specified length or precision.

```
SELECT ROUND(175.45, 0)
```

Output is:`175.00`

UPDATE:

If number is below 200 and you want to round to only one number after the decimal point and if it is above 200, you want to use use `CEILING`:

```
DECLARE @delimiter DECIMAL(10,5) = 200

SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN E.FooNumber < @delimiter THEN ROUND(e.FooNumber, 0)
    ELSE CEILING(e.FooNumber)
END AS FooNumbers
FROM   (VALUES(100.1),
              (180.4),
              (250.5),
              (350.8)) E(FooNumber)
```

Comment: In condition that the number is below 200 I want to round to only one number after the decimal point and if it is above 200 I  use CEILING. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the below query.

```
SELECT  TB_Product. ProductID, 
round(TB_Product.RetailPrice * 0.95) AS SpecialOfferPrice
```

for more information refer to this [link]https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_round.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT  TB_Product. ProductID, 
ROUND(TB_Product.RetailPrice * 0.95, -2) AS SpecialOfferPrice
```

Comment: In condition that the number is below 200 I want to round to only one number after the decimal point and if it is above 200 I use CEILING. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the CEILING(), FLOOR() functions.

This link goes further in explaination (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1589/sql-server-rounding-functions--round-ceiling-and-floor/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FLOOR() and CEILING() functions to round up or down respectively.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/floor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15